# How to get rid of wildcard return type with generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, javassist

Here is a code that uses Javassist for generating classes on the fly.

```
public class ClassGenerator {

    // ...

    public Class<? extends Base> generateClass(MetaData md) {
         // Call javassist api and returns a generated on the fly class...
    }
}
```

Later in the code, there is

```
public class GeneratorClient implements IClient<Base> {
   private Class<Base> clazz;

   public void init() {
      MetaData myMd = ...;

      clazz = generator.generateClass(myMd);

      // ...
   }

   public Base getClazz() {
       return clazz;
   }
}

public interface IClient<T extends Base> {
    T getClazz();
}
```

Obviously, the compiler raises an error here. Casting raises a warning *("Uncheked cast ...")*...

Suppressing the warning is not an option.

I can't write this also : `public class GeneratorClient implements IClient<? extends Base>`.

How can I change the return type of `ClassGenerator#generateClass` ?

**JDK 6**

Comment: Uhwell, make the return value (`clazz`) a `Class<? extends Base>`... Or do I misunderstand what you're after?

Comment: +1 @fge From what I understood , this is what he wants !!!

Comment: Well, my answer is still valid. `Class<Base>` is `Base.class`, it can be nothing else. If you want to grab a class object of a subclass of it, you have to do `Class<? extends Base>`. It would help if you told what you wanted to do exactly? As of yet, it is unclear.

Comment: See my answer (after rereading your code, I think I understand what you're after). However, I don't know what that Metadata is.

Comment: Metadata stores the information for generating the class. What is sure is that the generated class will inherit from Base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `GeneratorClient` declaration to this:

```
public class GeneratorClient<T extends Base> 
    implements IClient<T>
{
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    // etc
```

This should do it.

**EDIT** Since you only know the class at runtime, add a static factory method to build your `GeneratorClient`:

```
public static <T extends Base> GeneratorClient<T> forClass(final Class<T>)
{
    return new GeneratorClient<T>(whatever, args, are, needed, if, any);
}
```

In code:

```
final GeneratorClient<MyClass> = GeneratorClient.forClass(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: When it comes to instanciate GeneratorClient, the type class is only known at runtime not at compile time.

Comment: It's a more than CLEVER workaround although I still have a wildcard return type !

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean by "although I still have a wildcard return type"? :)

Comment: Note: Mockito uses the same thing for its `ArgumentCaptor`. You initiate it using `final ArgumentCaptor<X> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(X.class);` (the `final` is mine, out of pure habit; I am final-happy)

Comment: The ClassGenerator#generateClass is unchanged.

Comment: Well, why did it need changing? ;) That is the power of static factory methods combined with generics! In the JDK, you can find similar examples, for example in `EnumSet` (see `EnumSet.of()` for instance)